# Error in connecting to Mysql from nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have started node-js recently and i was trying to connect my nodejs server with mysql. 
The problem is i am getting an error, i really don't know why, i am using phpmyadmin.

Phpmyadmin details

user: root

host: localhost

password is not set

[This is the image of my phpmyadmin database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w16wn.png)

[This is the settings of my phpmyadmin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNCGc.png)

[This is the terminal where it is showing error connecting to DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kan8.png)

index.js

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var mysql = require('mysql');

     var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

     var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: "localhost",
     user: "root",
     database: "learning",
     });

   connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err) {
   console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
    }

  console.log('Connection established');
  console.log('3');

  connection.end(function(err) {
  console.log('Connection closed');
  console.log('4');

  process.exit();
  });
  });

  app.listen(port,function(err1){
  console.log("Listening on the port 3000");
  });
```

Comment: If there is no password try removing the password key/value

Comment: Also - just don't leave it unprotected in the long term!!

Comment: tried that, still getting the same error

Comment: change that to `console.log('Error connecting to Db', err)` and see where it is failing.

Comment: Error connecting to Db { Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Comment: try running npm i mysql in terminal and see if it updates

Comment: it got updated still it's showing the same error

Comment: Try adding `insecureAuth : true,` to your createconnection function

Comment: I've already tried that also

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I've got the Solution: I had changed the port from default 3306 of phpmyadmin mysql to 3308 therefore i added port: 3308 and it started working.'

Comment: Well done i'm glad you found a solution

Comment: No Problem That's what I'm here for

Answer (score 2):

connection to mysql from node js, you are use to mysql from node js connection

```
/config
  /database.js
/server.js
/.env

const http = require('http');
const app = require('express')();
require('./config/database.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.ServerPort, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  logger.info(`Express server listening on port ${process.env.ServerPort}`);
});
```

When you run this:

```
node server.js
```

database.js file

```
const My = require('jm-ez-mysql');

// Init DB Connection
const connection = My.init({
  host: process.env.DBHOST,
  user: process.env.DBUSER,
  password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  dateStrings: true,
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
  timezone: 'utc',
  multipleStatements: true,
  connectTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
});

module.exports = {
  connection,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the port from default 3306 of phpmyadmin mysql to 3308

therefore i added port: 3308 and it started working.

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 database: "learning",
 port: 3308
 });
```